# Combine multiple queries in postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, php-pgsql

I have 2 queries.
Query 1:-

```
select mr.id,count(ml.id) as labor_cnt 
from mreq Mr 
join mlbr ml on Mr.id = ml.mrid 
where Mr.id in(1235,3355) 
group by Mr.id
```

Query 2:-

```
select mr.id,count(mm.id) as mtrial_cnt 
from mreq Mr join mmrm mm on Mr.id = mm.mrid 
where Mr.id in(1235,3355) 
group by Mr.id
```

Trying to use union all but won't work. Suggest any alternative to combine them.

Comment: what you call combine?.. how results look for both queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're grouping by `mr.id` in both queries, I assume you want results something like:

```
 mr.id | labor_cnt | mtrial_cnt
--------------------------------
     1 |         5 |          3
     2 |      null |          6
     3 |         4 |          2
     4 |         3 |       null
...
```

If that's what you're looking for, then you can combine the queries with common table expressions. Something like:

```
WITH labor as (
  SELECT mr.id AS mrid, count(ml.id) AS labor_cnt
    FROM mreq mr JOIN mlbr ml ON mr.id = ml.mrid
    WHERE mr.id IN (1235, 3355)
  GROUP BY mr.id),

mtrial as (
  SELECT mr.id AS mrid, count(mm.id) AS mtrial_cnt
    FROM mreq mr JOIN mmrm mm ON mr.id = mm.mrid
    WHERE mr.id in (1235, 3355)
  GROUP BY mr.id)

SELECT COALESCE(l.mrid, m.mrid), l.labor_cnt, m.labor_cnt
  FROM labor l FULL OUTER JOIN mtrial m ON mrid
ORDER BY mrid;
```

**Edited to add**

It looks like you're using MySQL, and MySQL does not support common table expressions. MySQL does support subqueries, so this may work (note: I haven't verified the syntax, as I don't have a running MySQL instance available):

```
SELECT COALESCE(l.mrid, m.mrid), l.labor_cnt, m.labor_cnt
  FROM 
    (SELECT mr.id AS mrid, count(ml.id) AS labor_cnt
       FROM mreq mr JOIN mlbr ml ON mr.id = ml.mrid
       WHERE mr.id IN (1235, 3355)
     GROUP BY mr.id) AS labor

    FULL OUTER JOIN

    (SELECT mr.id AS mrid, count(mm.id) AS mtrial_cnt
       FROM mreq mr JOIN mmrm mm ON mr.id = mm.mrid
       WHERE mr.id in (1235, 3355)
     GROUP BY mr.id) AS mtrial

    ON mrid

ORDER BY mrid;
```

Comment: Yes somethink like this I am looking for.Might that works for me!! Thanks.

Comment: Getting  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'labor as ( SELECT mr.id AS mrid, count(ml.id) AS labor_cnt FROM ' at line 1

Comment: You labeled this as `postgresql`, so I used syntax for postgres. I'm not sure what the equivalent syntax would be with mysql.

Comment: I've added an unverified MySQL example. In the future, please be more careful with your tags.